# How can I anti aliase the measureit lines for the render result

Tags: node-editor, antialiasing

[image]

Ive set up this render template for some profiles and each gets a measureit dimension to render out with the result to save time putting it in afterwards, but I realized it is a bit jagged, how can i fix this with nodes so i can get a clean image out without re editing it ?